# SQL Error on update table from another table

Tags: sql, sql-update

I am trying to update one column of a database table from another table.

But always get the same error:

### #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM wp_popularpostsdata T1 INNER JOIN wp_top_ten T2 ON T1.postid = T2.postnumbe' at line 11

I find a post who talks about the error 1064, but not help me.

I've tried with this codes:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.pageviews = B.cntaccess
FROM wp_popularpostsdata A INNER JOIN wp_top_ten B ON A.postid = B.postnumber

UPDATE a
SET a.pageviews = b.cntaccess
FROM wp_popularpostsdata a JOIN wp_top_ten b ON a.postid = b.postnumber

UPDATE T1
SET T1.pageviews = T2.cntaccess
FROM wp_popularpostsdata T1 INNER JOIN wp_top_ten T2 ON T1.postid = T2.postnumber
WHERE 1;
```

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using MySQL so, according to that correction in your query:

```
UPDATE wp_popularpostsdata A
JOIN wp_top_ten B ON A.postid = B.postnumber
SET A.pageviews = B.cntaccess

UPDATE wp_popularpostsdata a
JOIN wp_top_ten b ON a.postid = b.postnumber
SET a.pageviews = b.cntaccess


UPDATE wp_popularpostsdata T1
JOIN wp_top_ten T2 ON T1.postid = T2.postnumber
SET T1.pageviews = T2.cntaccess
WHERE 1;
```

For general Update join :

**1. MYSQL**

```
UPDATE TABLEA a 
JOIN TABLEB b ON a.join_colA = b.join_colB  
SET a.columnToUpdate = [something]
```

**2.SQL SERVER OR MSSSQL**

```
UPDATE A
SET foo = B.bar
FROM TableA A
JOIN TableB B
    ON A.col1 = B.colx
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE wp_popularpostsdata A INNER JOIN wp_top_ten B ON A.postid = B.postnumber
SET A.pageviews = B.cntaccess

UPDATE wp_popularpostsdata a JOIN wp_top_ten b ON a.postid = b.postnumber
SET a.pageviews = b.cntaccess

UPDATE wp_popularpostsdata T1 INNER JOIN wp_top_ten T2 ON T1.postid = T2.postnumber
SET T1.pageviews = T2.cntaccess
WHERE 1;
```